# How to make authentication with React JS

Tags: reactjs, global-variables, token, access-token

I'm working on a simple frontend in react.js and a backend in node.js. At the moment I'm working on a Login that should work as follow:

- The Frontend send username and password to the backend
- Obtain a token that will be needed for all the following requests to the backend

Now all my files in the frontend should see the obtained token so they can use it to send the requests when needed, how can I do this, considering that not all the components in my React.js frontend are childs of the Login? Should I make a global variable? If yes how? Thank you in advance

Comment: How to you manage global state in your application? You have many options, using a `Context`, something like `redux` or `mobx` (and there are many more)

Answer (score 0):

After getting your token from node server, you can use `useContext()` hook of React and provide the token as value to the components. This is the simplest way in my opinion. Otherwise, if you are familiar with redux, flux etc, you can use them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the token you received from the backend and simply get it from localStorage when you need it.